# invalid conversion from ‘const int*’ to ‘int*’ in template function

Tags: c++

```
class A{
    private:
        T x;
    public:
        A():x(0){}
        A(T x1):x(x1){}

        void printInfo(const T& a){
            cout<<"Succes1"<<endl;
        }
};

class B{
    private:
        int x;
        A<int*> var;
    public:
        B():x(0){}
        B(int x1):x(x1){}

        void printInfo(const int * a){
            var.printInfo(a);
        }
};
```

The probelms is with

```
void printInfo(const int * a){
    var.printInfo(a);
}
```

It gives an error, saying invalid conversion from ‘const int*’ to ‘int*’

but works with `int *a` or `int *const a`

Shouldn't void printInfo in class A look like

```
void printInfo(const int* a)
```

Is this correct?

```cpp
cont int *p, //pointer to constant int

int* const p //constant pointer to int
```

if thats the case there should be error with

```
printInfo(int* const a)
```

not with

```
printInfo(const int * a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn't void printInfo in class A look like
>
> ```
> void printInfo(const int* a)
> ```
>
> Is this correct?

No, the problem ist that you declare `var` as `A<int*>` in `B`, so `A`'s

```
void printInfo(const T& a);
```

is really

```
void printInfo( int* const& a);
```

and not

```
void printInfo( int const* & a);
```

So, for the call in `B` to work you need to declare `var` as `A<int const*>`. See compiling version [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/633ebb8653e2d2df).

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> void printInfo(const int * a){
> ```
>
> Shouldn't void printInfo in class B look like
>
> ```
> void printInfo(const int* a)
> ```
>
> Is this correct?

Both are equivalent. In many cases, whitespace is not syntactically relevant.

> ```
> cont int *p, //pointer to constant int
>
> int* const p //constant pointer to int
> ```

These are correct.

> if thats the case there should be error with
>
> ```
> printInfo(int* const a)
> ```
>
> not with
>
> ```
> printInfo(const int * a)
> ```

The error should be when you attempt to implicitly convert a pointer to const into pointer to non-const.

Comment: I've meant to say Shouldn't void printInfo in class A look like void printInfo(const int* a). Then why does it trying to convert pointer to const into pointer to non const when functions parameters in both classes are the same